# Updating the range during while loop so no dupe guess

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop, python-3.4

```
import random  

print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!\n")  
print("We are going to pick a number and have the computer guess it.")  
answer = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 100:\n"))  
guess = random.randint(1, 100)  
guesses = 1  
while guess != answer:  
    if guess > answer:  
        guess = random.randint(1, guess)  
        print(guess)  
    elif guess < answer:  
        guess = random.randint(guess, 100)  
        print(guess)    
    guesses += 1  
print("\nWhoopy, I guessed correct.\n")  
print("It took me %s guesses to guess %s." % (guesses, answer))
```

This is what I have so far. I am not sure how to form the *if* and *elif* to make sure there isn't a dupe guess

Comment: What is the point of `guess = guess`?

Comment: That might be a useless piece of code. Let me do a check.

Comment: It was an oversight. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to have two extra variables that limit the bounds that your `guess` will be made in. Try this:

```
low = 1
high = 100
guess = random.randint(low, high)  
guesses = 1  
while guess != answer:
    if guess > answer:
        high = guess - 1
        print(guess)  
    elif guess < answer:  
        low = guess + 1
        print(guess) 
    guess = random.randint(low, high)     
    guesses += 1  
print("\nWhoopy, I guessed correct.\n")  
print("It took me %s guesses to guess %s." % (guesses, answer))
```

You'd actually do better though if you didn't guess randomly, and instead always picked the midpoint between `low` and `high`. That's the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: will you really do better? You'll definitely have a better worst case, but I think the average case should be about the same.

Comment: Had to run out. I'm going to try this in 30 min.

Comment: @genisage I believe you're right, since the random choice presumably has an ecpected value of the midpoint.

Comment: @genisage: In a quick test, randomly picking almost always requires more guesses. My algorithm analysis skills are really rusty, so I'm not sure how you'd calculate the average running time of the random version, but just from trying it a few dozen times it's clearly worse than what you get from picking the midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `min` and `max` variables to keep track of the current range.

```
min = 1; max = 100
guess = random.randint(min, max)  
guesses = 1  
while guess != answer:  
    if guess > answer:  
        min = guess+1  
        print(guess) 
    elif guess < answer:
        max = guess-1
        print(guess)
    guess = random.randint(min, max)    
    guesses += 1
```

Comment: Had to run out. I'm going to try this in 30 min.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to form the if and elif to make sure there isn't a dupe guess

You should start by binding a name to those `1`, `100` values.  Then you can meaningfully assign to them.

```
while guess != answer:
    if guess > answer:
        range_max = guess - 1
        guess = random.randint(range_min, guess)
        print(guess)
    elif guess < answer:
        range_min = guess + 1
        guess = random.randint(guess, range_max)
        print(guess)
    guesses += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just generate all the guesses at once and then prune the list of guesses of the guesses that are greater or smaller:

```
import random  

print("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game!\n")  
print("We are going to pick a number and have the computer guess it.")  
answer = int(input("Pick a number between 1 and 100:\n"))  
guesses=random.sample(range(1, 101), 100)
count = 1  
guess=guesses.pop()
while guess != answer:  
    if guess > answer:  
        guesses=[e for e in guesses if e<guess] 
        print(guess)  
    elif guess < answer:  
        guesses=[e for e in guesses if e>guess] 
        print(guess)    
    guess=guesses.pop()    
    count += 1  
print("\nWhoopy, I guessed correct.\n")  
print("It took me %s guesses to guess %s." % (count, answer))
```